# Skyrim guards not killling thugs in Whiterun

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am getting my ass kicked in *Whiterun* by some hired thugs because I stole something from someone. I am playing at *Master* difficulty and on *level 7* so I thought its better to run around and let the guards take these thugs but they are acting like nothing has happened.
I don't have any other saved game and I can't take on these thugs on my own. What should I do?

Comment: Guards are there to prevent you from mugging other people :p Other people mugging you however is NOT a crime!

Comment: Well, you made a crime, you stole some stuff. Maybe it\`s time to accept the consequences you deserve. Just sayin\`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did is somehow climb on the rocky area near Hall of the Dead and used Novice level fire spell. It took me around 40 minutes to kill all 3 of them. I also tried firing arrows from its roof but thugs hide themselves beneath me. [image: Whiterun]

Comment: Been there, done that. +1 for sheer tenacity.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Frenzy spell on the thugs and get them to attack the guards.  Mayhem will ensue, the thugs will be dead, and you will be able to saunter casually away.

Or, break line of sight, switch to light armour and try to sneak away.

It might even be possible to get yourself arrested and thrown in jail.  I've not tried that but there's a good chance it would work.

As a last resort, you could cheat.  I'd normally advise against it, but, if there's a situation where you're totally stuck, switching to God mode and running away could be an option.  It's better to cheat for a few seconds than have your game ruined.

Comment: Fwiw frenzy is a rather high level spell I doubt he can cast it at level 7.  Fury would work better at low levels.

Answer (score -2):

Hit and run, thats what i did, also even the jarl wont do anything and I thought he would

Answer (score -5):

If I was in that situation i would buy my follower lots of potions to regain health quickly and give my follower good armor/weapons and leave him/her to deal with the thugs